# How to allow 3 days consecutive shifts after 2 pairs of 2days consecutive shifts in CP-sat solver (or tools - python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, schedule, or-tools, cp-sat

This is a minimal reproducible problem that i am currently facing in my app.

I need to force the solver to obey the logic below:

- if there are any consecutive shifts, allow up to 2 pairs of 2days consecutive shifts and prevent any 3days:

  sum(pairs of 2-days shifts) < 2,

  sum(pairs of 3-days shifts) == 0
- if the pairs of 2days shifts are the max number (=2), then it should allow 1 pair of 3days consecutive shifts:

  sum(pairs of 2-days shifts) == 2,

  sum(pairs of 3-days shifts) <= 1

My setup:

- Python: 3.10
- Windows 10
- ortools: 9.6.2534

This is the code.

```
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model
from ortools.sat.python.cp_model import LinearExpr

shifts_can_not_work = [
    [[0], [1], [1], [1], [0], [1], [1], [0], [1], [1], [0], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1],
        [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1],
     ],
    [[0],[1],[1],[0],[1],[1],[1],[1],[0],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[0],[1],[1],[1],[1],[0],[0],[0],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],
        [1],[1],[1],
    ],
    [[0],[0],[0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1],
        [1], [1], [1],[1],[1],[1],[1],
    ],
    [[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[1],[0],[0],[0], [0], [0], [0],
        [0], [0], [0],
    ],
]


def main():
    # Data.
    num_nurses = 4
    num_shifts = 1
    num_days = 30
    all_nurses = range(num_nurses)
    all_shifts = range(num_shifts)
    all_days = range(num_days)

    # Creates the model.
    model = cp_model.CpModel()

    # Creates shift variables.
    # shifts[(n, d, s)]: nurse 'n' works shift 's' on day 'd'.
    shifts = {}
    for n in all_nurses:
        for d in all_days:
            for s in all_shifts:
                shifts[(n, d, s)] = model.NewBoolVar(f"shift_n{n}_d{d}_s{s}")
                
                
    # Each shift is assigned to exactly one nurse in the schedule period.
    for d in all_days:
        for s in all_shifts:
            model.AddExactlyOne(shifts[(n, d, s)] for n in all_nurses)

    # Each nurse works at most one shift per day.
    for n in all_nurses:
        for d in all_days:
            model.AddAtMostOne(shifts[(n, d, s)] for s in all_shifts)
    
    # Forbid working on particular shifts according to preferences in `shifts_can_not_work`
    for nurse in all_nurses:
        for day in all_days:
            for shift in all_shifts:
                model.Add(
                    shifts[(nurse, day, shift)] == shifts_can_not_work[nurse][day][shift]
                    if shifts_can_not_work[nurse][day][shift] == 0  
                    else shifts[(nurse, day, shift)] <= 1  
                )
    # Try to distribute the shifts evenly
    min_shifts_per_nurse = (num_shifts * num_days) // num_nurses
    if num_shifts * num_days % num_nurses == 0:
        max_shifts_per_nurse = min_shifts_per_nurse
    else:
        max_shifts_per_nurse = min_shifts_per_nurse + 1
    for n in all_nurses:
        shifts_worked = []
        for d in all_days:
            for s in all_shifts:
                shifts_worked.append(shifts[(n, d, s)])
        model.Add(min_shifts_per_nurse <= sum(shifts_worked))
        model.Add(sum(shifts_worked) <= max_shifts_per_nurse)

    allow_2day_3day(
        all_nurses=all_nurses,
        all_days=all_days,
        all_shifts=all_shifts,
        model=model,
        shifts=shifts,
        condays2_max_pairs=2,
        condays3_max_pairs=1,
    )

    # Creates the solver and solve.
    solver = cp_model.CpSolver()
    solver.parameters.linearization_level = 1
    # Enumerate all solutions.
    solver.parameters.enumerate_all_solutions = False

    class NursesPartialSolutionPrinter(cp_model.CpSolverSolutionCallback):
        """Print intermediate solutions."""

        def __init__(self, shifts, num_nurses, num_days, num_shifts, limit):
            cp_model.CpSolverSolutionCallback.__init__(self)
            self._shifts = shifts
            self._num_nurses = num_nurses
            self._num_days = num_days
            self._num_shifts = num_shifts
            self._solution_count = 0
            self._solution_limit = limit

        def on_solution_callback(self):
            self._solution_count += 1
            print(f"Solution {self._solution_count}\n")

            for n in range(self._num_nurses):
                print(f"\nNurse {n}\n")
                for d in range(self._num_days):
                 
                    is_working = False
                    for s in range(self._num_shifts):
                        if self.Value(self._shifts[(n, d, s)]):
                            is_working = True
                            print(f"\tDay {d} works shift {s}")
                    if not is_working:
                        print(f"\tDay {d} -- ")

            if self._solution_count >= self._solution_limit:
                self.StopSearch()

        def solution_count(self):
            return self._solution_count

    # Display the first five solutions.
    solution_limit = 1
    solution_printer = NursesPartialSolutionPrinter(shifts, num_nurses, num_days, num_shifts, solution_limit)
    status = solver.Solve(model=model, solution_callback=solution_printer)

    print("Status = %s" % solver.StatusName(status))
    # Statistics.
    print("\nStatistics")
    print(f"  - conflicts      : {solver.NumConflicts()}")
    print(f"  - branches       : {solver.NumBranches()}")
    print(f"  - wall time      : {solver.WallTime()} s")
    print(f"  - solutions found: {solution_printer.solution_count()}")


def allow_2day_3day(all_nurses, all_shifts, all_days, model, shifts, condays2_max_pairs: int, condays3_max_pairs: int):
    consecutive_shifts_var = {}
    consecutive_shifts_var = {f"{nurse}": [] for nurse in all_nurses}
    consecutive_shifts_var_condays3 = {f"{nurse}": [] for nurse in all_nurses}
    for nurse in all_nurses:
        for day in all_days:
            condays_vars = []
            if day not in (len(all_days) - 1,):
                equation = []
                var = model.NewBoolVar("BoolVar_2day_n%i_startday%i_endday%i" % (nurse, day, day + 1))
                consecutive_shifts_var[f"{nurse}"].append(var)
                condays_vars.append(var)
                for shift in all_shifts:
                    if (nurse, day, shift) in shifts:
                        if shifts[(nurse, day, shift)] not in equation:
                            equation.append(shifts[(nurse, day, shift)])
                    if (nurse, day + 1, shift) in shifts:
                        if shifts[(nurse, day + 1, shift)] not in equation:
                            equation.append(shifts[(nurse, day + 1, shift)])
                    if (nurse, day + 2, shift) in shifts:
                        if shifts[(nurse, day + 2, shift)] not in equation:
                            equation.append(shifts[(nurse, day + 2, shift)])
                if len(equation) != 0:
                    model.Add(LinearExpr.Sum(equation[:-1]) == 2).OnlyEnforceIf(var)
                    model.Add(LinearExpr.Sum(equation) != 2).OnlyEnforceIf(var.Not())

            if day not in (len(all_days) - 1, len(all_days) - 2, len(all_days) - 3):
                equation = []
                var_condays3 = model.NewBoolVar("BoolVar_3day_n%i_0_startday%i_endday%i" % (nurse, day, day + 2))
                consecutive_shifts_var[f"{nurse}"].append(var_condays3)
                condays_vars.append(var_condays3)
                for shift in all_shifts:
                    if (nurse, day, shift) in shifts:
                        if shifts[(nurse, day, shift)] not in equation:
                            equation.append(shifts[(nurse, day, shift)])
                    if (nurse, day + 1, shift) in shifts:
                        if shifts[(nurse, day + 1, shift)] not in equation:
                            equation.append(shifts[(nurse, day + 1, shift)])
                    if (nurse, day + 2, shift) in shifts:
                        if shifts[(nurse, day + 2, shift)] not in equation:
                            equation.append(shifts[(nurse, day + 2, shift)])
                if len(equation) != 0:
                    model.Add(LinearExpr.Sum(equation) == 3).OnlyEnforceIf(  
                        var_condays3
                    )
                    model.Add(LinearExpr.Sum(equation) != 3).OnlyEnforceIf(var_condays3.Not())

        condays2_bool_var = model.NewBoolVar("condays2_bool_var_n%d" % nurse)
        model.Add(LinearExpr.Sum(consecutive_shifts_var[f"{nurse}"]) <= condays2_max_pairs).OnlyEnforceIf(
            condays2_bool_var
        )
        model.Add(LinearExpr.Sum(consecutive_shifts_var[f"{nurse}"]) > 0).OnlyEnforceIf(condays2_bool_var)
        model.Add(LinearExpr.Sum(consecutive_shifts_var[f"{nurse}"]) == 0).OnlyEnforceIf(condays2_bool_var.Not())

        # 3day
        condays3_bool_var = model.NewBoolVar("condays3_bool_var_n%d" % nurse)
        model.Add(LinearExpr.Sum(consecutive_shifts_var_condays3[f"{nurse}"]) <= condays3_max_pairs).OnlyEnforceIf(
            condays3_bool_var.Not()
        )
        model.Add(LinearExpr.Sum(consecutive_shifts_var_condays3[f"{nurse}"]) > 0).OnlyEnforceIf(condays3_bool_var)
        model.Add(LinearExpr.Sum(consecutive_shifts_var_condays3[f"{nurse}"]) == 0).OnlyEnforceIf(
            condays3_bool_var.Not()
        )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Output:**

Nurse 0

```
Day 0 -- 
Day 1 -- 
Day 2 -- 
Day 3 works shift 0
Day 4 -- 
Day 5 -- 
Day 6 works shift 0
Day 7 -- 
Day 8 -- 
Day 9 -- 
Day 10 -- 
Day 11 -- 
Day 12 -- 
Day 13 works shift 0
Day 14 -- 
Day 15 -- 
Day 16 works shift 0
Day 17 -- 
Day 18 -- 
Day 19 works shift 0
Day 20 -- 
Day 21 -- 
Day 22 works shift 0
Day 23 -- 
Day 24 -- 
Day 25 works shift 0
Day 26 -- 
Day 27 -- 
Day 28 works shift 0
Day 29 --
```

Nurse 1

```
Day 0 -- 
Day 1 -- 
Day 2 -- 
Day 3 -- 
Day 4 works shift 0
Day 5 -- 
Day 6 -- 
Day 7 -- 
Day 8 -- 
Day 9 works shift 0
Day 10 -- 
Day 11 -- 
Day 12 works shift 0
Day 13 -- 
Day 14 -- 
Day 15 works shift 0
Day 16 -- 
Day 17 -- 
Day 18 works shift 0
Day 19 -- 
Day 20 -- 
Day 21 -- 
Day 22 -- 
Day 23 works shift 0
Day 24 -- 
Day 25 -- 
Day 26 works shift 0
Day 27 -- 
Day 28 -- 
Day 29 works shift 0
```

Nurse 2

```
Day 0 -- 
Day 1 -- 
Day 2 -- 
Day 3 -- 
Day 4 -- 
Day 5 -- 
Day 6 -- 
Day 7 works shift 0
Day 8 -- 
Day 9 -- 
Day 10 works shift 0
Day 11 -- 
Day 12 -- 
Day 13 -- 
Day 14 works shift 0
Day 15 -- 
Day 16 -- 
Day 17 works shift 0
Day 18 -- 
Day 19 -- 
Day 20 -- 
Day 21 works shift 0
Day 22 -- 
Day 23 -- 
Day 24 works shift 0
Day 25 -- 
Day 26 -- 
Day 27 works shift 0
Day 28 -- 
Day 29 --
```

Nurse 3

```
Day 0 works shift 0
Day 1 works shift 0
Day 2 works shift 0
Day 3 -- 
Day 4 -- 
Day 5 works shift 0
Day 6 -- 
Day 7 -- 
Day 8 works shift 0
Day 9 -- 
Day 10 -- 
Day 11 works shift 0
Day 12 -- 
Day 13 -- 
Day 14 -- 
Day 15 -- 
Day 16 -- 
Day 17 -- 
Day 18 -- 
Day 19 -- 
Day 20 works shift 0
Day 21 -- 
Day 22 -- 
Day 23 -- 
Day 24 -- 
Day 25 -- 
Day 26 -- 
Day 27 -- 
Day 28 -- 
Day 29 --
```

**The problem is that Nurse 3 has one pair of 3days, but no pairs of 2days.**

What am i not doing right with the Booleans?